# Set Component property using a var

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components

I want to do this:

```
    Transform trans = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
    string propertyName = "position";

   trans[propertyName] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

How can i do this part in c# `trans[propertyName]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reflection you can achieve this:

```
Transform trans = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
Debug.Log(typeof(Transform).GetProperty("position").GetValue(trans, null));
```

will give you the position of the transform you got. Note that it can be simplified by directly accessing the transform with

```
Transform trans = gameObject.transform;
```

For setting values, which is what you're asking about:

```
typeof(Transform).GetProperty("position").SetValue(gameObject.transform, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), null);
```